# What is the best approach to handle long tasks in a django app

Tags: python, django, multithreading, asynchronous

So I have one function where clients uploads files and does a little parsing and then proceeds to send these results using another API. Now each file takes around 30 seconds to complete and a large deal of that is a POST request im making and awaiting an answer for 25 seconds.

My initial solution was that when a client sent a request about this particular function of my app I'd just loop through all those files until the task was completed and then sent back a http response. Of course I noticed that I started getting 504 error because it was taking too long.

My second, and current, solution is to respond with a http response immediately containing an empty html page where I then use javascript to use fetch to make calls to this function(a django view) and continually update the page and tell the client that a file has been processed. I also introduced threads to this solution and to my surprise it made it a lot faster, I suppose that is because each thread can get to that point where it waits for the long POST request so going from one to two almost doubled the speed etc.

Now my question is whether this approach is good, acceptable or if I should have done it another way completely. I've heard that django is supposedly thread-safe so I suppose there is no negative in creating more threads to solve the problem faster. I've heard about libraries as Celery but in my quick research it seemed harder to implement than just adding more threads and calling the long running function from javascript.

As I said I've tried just letting it get the request from the client, processing those files one by one and letting it return but it takes too long and the clients risk getting 504 errors. Doing it with javascript and continually updating the page letting the client know is my current and seems to be working but I'm uncertain if its good programming etiquette and what not.

Comment: using task queue would be better

Comment: task queue (celery or python-rq)  |  web sockets ( django-channels)